# Email on Angular Back End Configuration - Emailjs

Tags: node.js, angular

I´m trying to use the [emailjs](https://github.com/eleith/emailjs) in my project to send email confirmations. Problem is I can´t make this right.

Here is my code:

```
let SMTPClient = require('emailjs');

const options = {
  user: 'contact@stackoverflow.com.br',
  password: 'stackoverflow',
  host: 'mail.stackoverflow.com.br',
  port: '587',
  ssl: false,
  tls: true,
  timeout: 5000,
  domain: 'stackoverflow.com.br',
  authentication: ['LOGIN']
};

const headers = {
  from: 'contact@stackoverflow.com.br',
  to: 'myemail@gmail.com',
  cc: '',
  bcc: '',
  text: 'Text sample. Just a text.',
  subject: 'Title test',
  attachment: '',
};

  var client = new SMTPClient(options);
  let message = new SMTPClient.Message (headers);
  client.send(message, function (err, message) {
    console.log(err || message);
  });
```

But I keep getting the "SMTPClient is not a constructor". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Try using node-mailer

Comment: Thank you @SrinathKamath, worked like a charm. I did it in 5 minutes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone was searching for the same thing, I just used node-mailer as @SrinathKamath suggested and it worked perfectly.